# Reporting Cox & Snell and Nagelkerke in logistical regression

Tags: regression

As part of an assignment, I've been asked to report Cox & Snell and Nagelkerke values for my (logistical) regression analyses. I have been asked to interpret them as well as discuss what they suggest for the data. 
I am a bit confused to what they show, and how I should report them. Also, how do I know if they're important? I am really stuck on how to answer this question.

Many Thanks

Comment: You should find the information you need in the linked answer. Please read that thread. If there is something you still need to know afterwords, come back here & edit this to state what you've learned & what you still need to understand. Then we can provide what you need without simply duplicating information elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: where do I find that? Thank you

Comment: The link at the top to the duplicate question.